# How do I dismiss a sheet with the escape key?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

My app displays an `NSWindow` as a sheet. The `NSWindow` has various controls for settings properties of an object (an NSTextfield, a `NSDatepicker` etc) and two `NSButton`'s, 'Add' and 'Cancel' which are used to confirm or cancel the action.

I have set the key equivalent of the 'Add' button to `enter` and the key equivalent of `Cancel` to `escape`. This does not have the desired affect. I think this is due to the other controls handling the keypress events.

How do I configure my sheet so that the buttons behave as described?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to not just check your work, but to double check it!

The setup as described in the question works perfectly. (I have two similar sheets and I was using the wrong one.)